# Found KeyLogger in Windows 10 OS?

Tags: windows, keyloggers, windows-10, anomaly-detection

I was Running Yara, The pattern matching swiss knife for malware researchers on the Windows 10.

I ran a scan using rules from Yara Rules from YARA Rules Github and MalwareConfig rules.

I stumbled upon these DLL that had Signatures that matched escalate privileges, and Keyloggers.

- avicap32.dll
- mscorlib.dll
- AcGenerl.dll
- accessibilitycpl.dll
- adalsql.dll
- AtBroker.exe
- etc

To me it makes sense AcGenerl.dll has a keylogger signatures because it handles keyboard but MsCorlib.dll? it doesn't make sense why it has these signatures.

Any Explanations of why some of these Windows DLL raise flags? (not Intrested why my rules picked up but specifically the programs and libraries)

[Edit] Virus Total also says that these files are not infected by malware or a rootkit.

Could some of these be backdoors?
[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure `MSCorlib.dll` is a .NET DLL, but I might be wrong.

Comment: please consult your rules to find out why it was returned - https://www.us-cert.gov/sites/default/files/publications/AR-17-20045_Enhanced_Analysis_of_GRIZZLY_STEPPE_Activity.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **avicap32.dll** is a system process, and uses Windows API to **capture** AVI
  formatted content.
- **mscorlib.dll** is Multi-language (Microsoft) Standard
  Common Object Runtime Library.
- **AcGenral.dll** is the Windows Compatibility DLL, might be logging information to see if everything went well. I'm not sure about this one.
- **accessibilitycpl.dll** is the ease of access control panel. Possible that ease of access needs special permissions in order to work proper, logging of keys could be one.
- **adalsql.dll** is Active Directory Authentication Library for SQL Server. An authentication service does handle keyboard stuff and has to log them.
- **AtBroker.exe** appears to be Transitions Accessible technologies
  between desktops. According to [fixoserror.com](http://www.fixoserror.com/how-to-fix-atbroker-exe-error-is-it-safe.html).

It appears to be almost all of these are handling keyboard actions. About, mscorlib.dll it also appears to be used during creation of keyloggers. On [turkhackteam.org](http://www.turkhackteam.org/tht-yardim-merkezi/775218-keylogger-help-mee-2.html) there's a keylogger thread and debug results provides a mscorlib file. Also about mscorlib this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402582/mscorlib-dll-system-dll) link may give you some great ideas.